# Does anyone know where I can get the Scifi's FTL News Feed

Tags: tv

For a few years after the launch of the Sci-fi channel they aired FTL Newsfeed, a series of short news segments from the future.  I was wondering if they ever were collected in order somewhere?  I have been able to find bits and pieces of it on youtube, but not a contiguous whole I could watch beginning to end.

Comment: Is it legitimately distributable for free? Of not, the question becomes either off-topic "where to buy it" or off-topic "how can I illegally obtain it". If they were legitimately distributable, a simple Google search should find a good source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This series is NOT free to distribute, it's covered by trademarks and copyrights for a while yet. The best site for info on this series, with transcripts and other useful data is:

http://ftlnewsfeed.wikia.com/wiki/FTL_Newsfeed_Wiki

Comment: I am more than willing to get it from a legitimate source, I would just like to watch all the way though at least once.  In point of fact, a legitimate source would be preferred.